# trying to select data in mysql table in between two dates but code showing error

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code which i am using for my requirment guide me the right one pls. Hope this is enough for understand .

```
<?php
$t1 = $_POST['t1'];
$t2 = $_POST['t2'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","agni","gyaninfra");
$s=mysqli_query($con,"select * from shahabad where 'date' between '$t1' and 
'$t2';");
echo "<br>";
echo "<table border='2'><tr class='autostyle'><td colspan='4'>SHAHABAD 
RESORT ACCOUNT BOOK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>SR.NO.</td><td>Date</td>
  <td>Particulars</td><td>Debit/Credit</td>
  <td>Amount</td><td>Note</td><td>Recipt Image</td></tr>";
while($k=mysqli_fetch_array($s))
{   
$a= $k['tr_img'];
echo "<tr><td>".$k['sr_no']."</td><td>".$k['date'].
   "</td><td>".$k['particulars']."</td><td>".$k['transaction'].
   "</td><td>".$k['amount']."</td><td>".$k['note'].
   "</td><td>"."<img height=100 widht=100 src ='$a'>"."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Kill those single quotes around `date`: `select * from shahabad where date between '$t1' and 
'$t2';` ... but you should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your code by this. You place Single Quote in table field that is not valid.

```
<?php
    $t1 = $_POST['t1'];
    $t2 = $_POST['t2'];

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","agni","gyaninfra");
    $s=mysqli_query($con,"select * from shahabad where `date` between '$t1' and '$t2';");
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<table border='2'><tr class='autostyle'><td colspan='4'>SHAHABAD 
    RESORT ACCOUNT BOOK</td></tr>
      <tr><td>SR.NO.</td><td>Date</td>
      <td>Particulars</td><td>Debit/Credit</td>
      <td>Amount</td><td>Note</td><td>Recipt Image</td></tr>";
    while($k=mysqli_fetch_array($s))
    {   
    $a= $k['tr_img'];
    echo "<tr><td>".$k['sr_no']."</td><td>".$k['date'].
       "</td><td>".$k['particulars']."</td><td>".$k['transaction'].
       "</td><td>".$k['amount']."</td><td>".$k['note'].
       "</td><td>"."<img height=100 widht=100 src ='$a'>"."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$t1 = $_POST['t1'];
$t2 = $_POST['t2'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","agni","gyaninfra");
$s=mysqli_query($con,"select * from shahabad where `date` between '".$t1."' and 
'".$t2."';");
echo "<br>";
echo "<table border='2'><tr class='autostyle'><td colspan='4'>SHAHABAD 
RESORT ACCOUNT BOOK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>SR.NO.</td><td>Date</td>
  <td>Particulars</td><td>Debit/Credit</td>
  <td>Amount</td><td>Note</td><td>Recipt Image</td></tr>";
while($k=mysqli_fetch_array($s))
{   
$a= $k['tr_img'];
echo "<tr><td>".$k['sr_no']."</td><td>".$k['date'].
   "</td><td>".$k['particulars']."</td><td>".$k['transaction'].
   "</td><td>".$k['amount']."</td><td>".$k['note'].
   "</td><td>"."<img height=100 widht=100 src ='$a'>"."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

TRY this code :D